# How Can I Handle FirebaseAuthException?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I coded self-defined function for checking email and password with using Firebase, as follows;

```
Future<bool> loginCheck(ref) async {
  // loadingStart();
  try {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: loginIdController.text,
      password: loginPassController.text,
    );
    // loadingEnd();
    return Future<bool>.value(true);
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // print(e.code);
      //Do something
    } else if (e.code == 'network-request-failed') {
      //Do something
    } else {
      //Do something
      // loadingEnd();
    return Future<bool>.value(false);
  }
```

However, under `FirebaseAuthException catch (e){}`  always error occurs like screen shot below.

[image]

I'm sorry that I'm very new about not only flutter/firebase but vscode, and could not detect the reason why I cannot catch the error appropriately.

Could someone advise me why this happen ? thanks for your kindness.

Comment: can you recheck your provided data is matched with console data

Comment: Thanks for reply, but sorry that I could not get what actually `provided data` and `console data ` are ? How can I recheck those factors ?

Comment: User input email and password , and check if the user already signUp, if the user is new, he needs to create an account, then he will be able to log in

Comment: Yes, the User exist already exist in FireBase and I tried based on the created account

Comment: can you recheck the user input email

Comment: I did and when I fill the correct email. and password as well

Comment: With signOut() status right ?

Comment: Sorry cant say, you can try with other user data. also try to add break point on `signInWithEmailAndPassword` to check input data

Comment: No I'm really sorry that I did not understand about breakPoint

Comment: this problem has occurred, cause just I miss added breakpoint.... and I still do not understand how to user breakpoint on debugging.. So this is my chance to learn this way. I'm really sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: If you put the break point, the program will be freezed on that point and you can see the variable

Comment: thanks and will try it hereafter !

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a breakpoint. See the red circle on the side of the line the code crashed at. Click it to remove it. They are used for debugging and checking the flow of your code

Also in the bottom left of the second screenshot you can see the breakpoint again and the options for catching breakpoints and errors. Learn these too